# C++/Win32 How to load a function every second

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, timer

I am writing a program in which I want to call a function every second. I use GetSystemTime() to get the time and I have stated an if to check whether the previous second is equal to the current second or not, and if it isn't, load the function. Here's the code:

```
int prevsec = cursec;
SYSTEMTIME systime;
GetSystemTime(&systime);
cursec = systime.wSecond;
curmsec = systime.wMilliseconds;
if ( curmsec - prevmsec > 100 )
{
    prevmsec = curmsec;
    startgame();
}
if ( prevsec != cursec )
{
    prevmsec = 0;
    startfunction();
}
```

My only problem is, I don't know where to put it; if I put it at the beginning of my Windows Procedure, as I currently have, it will check if it should load the function every time a new message is sent, therefore when the window is open and you aren't doing anything, it won't check if the time has changed and therefore it won't work properly. I want to know if there is a place where I can put the code so it just keeps on checking the time (like in a infinite while loop) without seeing the "not responding" message. I hope you understood the question, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get a WM_TIMER message once every second.

**Note:** Windows isn't super-reliable about this sort of thing.  You might go several seconds between messages, or get several in a short time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! I set a timer when the window was created and in the WM_TIMER section, I told it to load the function and set another timer. I was thinking a whole day to find a solution. Thank you! I will set this as best answer as soon as I can.

Comment: You should only need to use it once - and then you'll get a WM_TIMER message every second until you shut it down.  If you create more timers every time it calls, you'll wind up with a lot of timers.

Comment: Oh, thanks for telling me! No wonder my program kept getting slower the more it was open... :D